# How to set HttpCookie Samesite attribute in .Net framework 4.0.30319?

Tags: google-chrome, security, cross-browser, httpcookie, samesite

I'm currently using .Net framework 4.0 in my application. Upon checking i could see that the samesite attribute is available only from .Net framework 4.7.2 version(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcookie?view=netframework-4.0). Can anyone please let me know how to set samesite=None without upgrading the .Net version or How to handle samesite cookie in .Net version 4.0

Answer (score -2):

Despite what Microsoft's documentation currently says about the minimum version, it does work on .NET 4.0, at least if you do it in your config file. Example:

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: The problem is not about the session cookie